# Constantly Updating JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm currently working on a project where I convert the time into base 10 time (essentially it will end up displaying a percentage of the day that has passed. ex: 12:00 noon would be displayed as 50.00 in base 10 time). Currently, I know my algorithm is correct since it prints out correctly if I print it to the console, but for some reason, I can't get my GUI to display. If I get rid of the part where I attempt to constantly update the GUI to display the correct numbers, the GUI displays fine, but with no numbers. My code is as follows:

```
package ClockPackage;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClockView extends Application {
    Pane background;
    static Text firstDigit;
    static Text secondDigit;
    static Text thirdDigit;
    static Text fourthDigit;
    Text middleDecimal;

    /* Sets the first digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setFirstDigit(char x1) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += x1;
        firstDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Sets the second digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setSecondDigit(char x2) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += x2;
        secondDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Sets the third digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setThirdDigit(char y1) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += y1;
        thirdDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Sets the fourth digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setFourthDigit(char y2) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += y2;
        fourthDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Main Method that Launches the GUI */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            final double TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y = 200;

            //Background Pane
            background = new Pane();

            //First digit textField
            firstDigit = new Text();
            firstDigit.setLayoutX(17);
            firstDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
            firstDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

            //Second digit textField
            secondDigit = new Text();
            secondDigit.setLayoutX(117);
            secondDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
            secondDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

            //Middle decimal
            middleDecimal = new Text(".");
            middleDecimal.setLayoutX(219);
            middleDecimal.setLayoutY(210);
            middleDecimal.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 72pt;");

            //Third digit textField
            thirdDigit = new Text();
            thirdDigit.setLayoutX(250);
            thirdDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
            thirdDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

            //Fourth digit textField
            fourthDigit = new Text();
            fourthDigit.setLayoutX(362);
            fourthDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
            fourthDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

            /* Adding the Nodes to the Pane */
            background.getChildren().addAll(firstDigit, secondDigit, middleDecimal, thirdDigit, fourthDigit);

            /* Setting the Scene */
            Scene scene = new Scene(background, 470, 258);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Base 10 Clock");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            /*
             * Calculates the time in base 10 time and calls the 4 methods
             * to set the GUI display.
             * 
             * In a constant while loop in order to continuously update
             * the GUI.
             */
            Calendar now;
            double currentTime;
            String timeString;
            long timestamp;
            while(true) {
                /* Sleep for 8.64 seconds since that is how long it is between
                increments of 0.01 in base 10 time. */
                Thread.sleep(8640);
                now = Calendar.getInstance();
                timestamp = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60*60 + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)*60 + now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                currentTime = timestamp/86400.0;
                timeString = "" + currentTime;
                setFirstDigit(timeString.charAt(2));
                setSecondDigit(timeString.charAt(3));
                setThirdDigit(timeString.charAt(4));
                setFourthDigit(timeString.charAt(5));
            }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I would go about making the GUI both show up and update the numbers constantly? I can't figure out how to get it to do both. I've seen where people use buttons to update data, but I haven't seen where the display is constantly automatically updated.

Thanks!

Comment: `while(true)`  -< Never do this in a `JavaFX` program in the GUI thread. Use [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) class.

Comment: [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) may be more suitable for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClockView extends Application {
    Pane background;
    static Text firstDigit;
    static Text secondDigit;
    static Text thirdDigit;
    static Text fourthDigit;
    Text middleDecimal;

    public final Timer clockTimer = new Timer();


    /* Sets the first digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setFirstDigit(char x1) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += x1;
        firstDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Sets the second digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setSecondDigit(char x2) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += x2;
        secondDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Sets the third digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setThirdDigit(char y1) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += y1;
        thirdDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Sets the fourth digit of the base 10 time to the passed through char. */
    static void setFourthDigit(char y2) {
        String digitString = "";
        digitString += y2;
        fourthDigit.setText(digitString);
    }

    /* Main Method that Launches the GUI */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final double TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y = 200;

        //Background Pane
        background = new Pane();

        //First digit textField
        firstDigit = new Text("0");
        firstDigit.setLayoutX(17);
        firstDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
        firstDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

        //Second digit textField
        secondDigit = new Text("0");
        secondDigit.setLayoutX(117);
        secondDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
        secondDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

        //Middle decimal
        middleDecimal = new Text(".");
        middleDecimal.setLayoutX(219);
        middleDecimal.setLayoutY(210);
        middleDecimal.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 72pt;");

        //Third digit textField
        thirdDigit = new Text("0");
        thirdDigit.setLayoutX(250);
        thirdDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
        thirdDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

        //Fourth digit textField
        fourthDigit = new Text("0");
        fourthDigit.setLayoutX(362);
        fourthDigit.setLayoutY(TEXTFIELD_LAYOUT_Y);
        fourthDigit.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 96pt;");

        /* Adding the Nodes to the Pane */
        background.getChildren().addAll(firstDigit, secondDigit, middleDecimal, thirdDigit, fourthDigit);

        /* Setting the Scene */
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 470, 258);
        Group root = (Group)scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(background);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Base 10 Clock");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        clockTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                Calendar now;
                double currentTime;
                String timeString;
                long timestamp;

                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    /*
                     * Calculates the time in base 10 time and calls the 4 methods
                     * to set the GUI display.
                     * 
                     * In a constant while loop in order to continuously update
                     * the GUI.
                     */
                    now = Calendar.getInstance();
                    timestamp = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60*60 + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)*60 + now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    currentTime = timestamp/86400.0;
                    timeString = "" + currentTime;
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override  public void run() {
                            setFirstDigit(timeString.charAt(2));
                            setSecondDigit(timeString.charAt(3));
                            setThirdDigit(timeString.charAt(4));
                            setFourthDigit(timeString.charAt(5));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 8640  // Sleep for 8.64 seconds since that is how long it is between
        );              // increments of 0.01 in base 10 time.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not good.  This changes the scene graph off of the JavaFX application thread, which can cause [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  Appropriate use of [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) can fix this.

Comment: @jewelsea Changed the gui updates to use the Platform.runLater as suggested.  A better MVC design would help.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

> Replace:

```
    Calendar now;
    double currentTime;
    String timeString;
    long timestamp;
    while (true)
    {
        /* Sleep for 8.64 seconds since that is how long it is between
            increments of 0.01 in base 10 time. */
        Thread.sleep(8640);
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        timestamp = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 * 60 + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 + now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        currentTime = timestamp / 86400.0;
        timeString = "" + currentTime;
        setFirstDigit(timeString.charAt(2));
        setSecondDigit(timeString.charAt(3));
        setThirdDigit(timeString.charAt(4));
        setFourthDigit(timeString.charAt(5));
    }
```

> with:

```
        Timeline overEightSeconsWonder = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(8.64), (ActionEvent event) ->
        {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            long timestamp = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 * 60 + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 + now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            double currentTime = timestamp / 86400.0;
            String timeString = "" + currentTime;
            setFirstDigit(timeString.charAt(2));
            setSecondDigit(timeString.charAt(3));
            setThirdDigit(timeString.charAt(4));
            setFourthDigit(timeString.charAt(5));
        }));
        overEightSeconsWonder.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        overEightSeconsWonder.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `while(true)` loop with a new thread or a service call with another thread.  The main thread is already responsible for updating the UI, so when you have some kind of blocking (IO, loops that take a long time, etc...), it will prevent the UI thread from updating.

[Link to the Service interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)

Create a service:

```
public static class TimeService extends Service<String> {

    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                // TODO: Do work - return the date/time as a String
                // If you need a Thread.sleep, use a spawn a new thread
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
TimeService timeService = new TimeService();
timeService.restart();
```

You could also do all sorts of things like binding UI elements to properties in the TimeService (that way the UI will "just update" as the service is running).